# Particle system with combined meshes and lights

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, light

I am trying to do something in Cycles with a particle system. I have made a city using 37 different cubes with unique textures on a particle system emitting from a pane.

On some of the buildings I would like to add exterior lights which you can observe on real sky scrapers.

I tried to just join the lights to one of the cubes using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> but to no avail am I able to produce the building with lights on the exterior.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site. Where is the PS here is not so clear for me. But if the point is to use particles which emit light, You can go to the "render" part of the PS panel and choose "object" and either use a lamp as object or any other object which is emissive.

Comment: thank you very much for the response. I was referring to those lights around the base I have added. I wish to add those to this building in a manner that they will appear and emit light on every hair they appear on, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> will work only with meshes so your solution cannot work, and also unfortunately Blender doesn't allow group hierarchies (like group of groups).

So, if you don't want to create mesh light emitters, that can be easily <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>'d (but from your screenshot I see that you want to use spot lights, so mesh emitters won't help), I'd suggest to

#### Create a different particle system for each one of the "complex" buildings

- Remove all the buildings with "lamp" lights from your original particle  system's dupligroup ("*Object*" menu > "*Groups*" > uncheck the existing group)
- For each building that has lamps, hoping they are just a little fraction of your 37:

  - create a new particle system on the emitter plane (by duplicating the original one, making it "single user", and reducing the number of particles on both by ~ 1/37 and 36/37 respectively)
  - use *Render*>*Group* and check the "*Whole Group*" option
  - **create a group containing only the building and its lamps**
  - **assign this group to the "*Dupli Group*" of the new particle system**
  - change the *Seed* of the emitter until you remove overlaps with already existing buildings

---

---

Edit:

#### an illustrated version of the above

Say you have a situation like this, where a *Group* of buildings is being used by a Particle System to create the city by duplication:

[image]

Select the building on which you would like to add the lights, go to its "*Object*" properties, and remove it from the group:

[image]

Go back to the particle system and reduce the number of buildings for the "main" group, that now has only the buildings with no lights:

[image]

Now create the spotlights, select the lights and then the building, and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to create a new group:

[image]

Then go back to the emitter plane, and **{1}** create a new particle system, **{2}** apply the settings of the already existing particle system, then **{3}** click on the "`2`" to make it single-user (*i.e.* an independent particle system created from a copy of the original)

[image]

Finally, on the new particle system, reduce the number to a small value (as many buildings with light you want); select the newly created group (probably `Group.001`) as your *DupliGroup*; set "*Whole Group*" as dupli option:

[image]

If you have created the group in the correct way, the building should be correctly placed in the vertical direction. They will be, however, a little bit displaced horizontally from the emitter plane (especially if the spot lights are not exactly vertical). To fix this, play around with the "*Offset*" settings of the light's "*Object*">"*Group*">`Group.001` properties until all the buildings lay on the city's floor.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your response, yes I am trying to get spot lights to appear on the exterior of the buildings. I have designed simple looking lights with spot lights to add on. I tried using mesh emitters but I found the light to spread to erratically to look real.  Thank you again for the help, I do not think I will be able to complete that as I am a novice at best.

Comment: Don't give up :) You are basically 80% there. I'd complement my answer with some animation but unfortunately I haven't got much more time today

Comment: @joeblendbag I've added some "visual" instructions. Hope they can be of help.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! My god that is such a well written answer it is greatly appreciated !!!! I just looked it over quickly and I feel as though I will be able to follow that easily now! Thank you so much!!